# React Web Audio API - Play, pause and export loaded audio file

Tags: reactjs, web-audio-api

My purpose is to upload and listen to an audio file using the WEB Audio API. I have been able to listen to the audio file when selecting it, but having trouble pausing and playing it afterwards. I need to export the file to WAV format aswell. I have created a simple example, any help will be much appreciated

**Loading Audio and playing it from file input**

```
const onFileChange = (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    setFile(file);

    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function (ev) {
      audioContext.decodeAudioData(ev.target.result).then(function (buffer) {
        playSound(buffer);
      });
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
```

**Play sound using buffer source**

```
  const playSound = (buffer, time) => {
    source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(audioContext.destination);
    source.start(time);
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };
```

**I'm facing problem here with pausing and playing:**

```
  const onPlayPause = (e) => {
    console.log("audioState", audioContext.state);
    console.log("duration", audioContext.currentTime);
    if (!isPlaying) {
      //source.start();
      setIsPlaying(true);
    } else if (audioContext.state === "running") {
      setPlayDuration(audioContext.currentTime);
      audioContext.suspend();
      setIsPlaying(false);
    } else if (audioContext.state === "suspended") {
      audioContext.resume();
    }
  };
```

**Export Audio:**

```
  const exportAudioFile = () => {

    offlineContext.render().then((buffer) => {
      setRenderState('encoding');
      const handleMessage = ({ data }) => {
        var blob = new window.Blob([new DataView(data)], {
          type: 'audio/wav',
        });

    //blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "audio/wav" });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      }

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  })};
```

Codesandboxlink:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-audiocontext-pause-play-fw20u?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hm, why? If you have complete files already, you can play those with `<audio>` just fine, no need for complicated Web Audio API work? Also, remember that links should only be _in addition_ to having [all the details in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Demo links are fine (only if a runnable snippet can't be used, that is), but not if you're not showing the code that's causing problems in your post =)

Comment: Oh I will update the question with some code blocks, In my main project I am modifying the input audio sound and will export the edited one. Not sure if <audio> playback will work in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had my fair share of headaches with persisting things in react functional components. Fortunately, useRef is an awesome tool for just that:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

As the documentation says, it essentially returns a container which `.current` property persists *across re-renders*.

I forked your code to useRef in action:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-audiocontext-pause-play-forked-si59u?file=/src/App.js:120-159

Basically, when you load the file, store your shiny new `AudioContext` in the ref's `.current` field, and reference that throughout the rest of your component. You can clean it up a bit, IE store the `.current` in a constant scoped to the function you're using it in.

Two key spots:

```js
export default function App() {
   const audioCtxContainer = useRef(null);
   ...
```

and

```js
    audioCtxContainer.current = new AudioContext();
    audioCtxContainer.current
        .decodeAudioData(ev.target.result)
        .then(function (buffer) {
          playSound(buffer);
        });
```

useRef is useful for any mutable object that you want to persist for the lifetime of the component.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot, stoping the audio context causes the audioContext Interface to close the audio context, releasing any system audio resources that it uses. Thus I lose the bufferstate and other audioContext data. Is there a way to call `PlaySound()` to start from beginning  after clicking the stop button. I mean maybe storing the buffer data or is there other way? Also is there a way to rewind 10 sec of the playing sound, like editing the `audioContext.current.currentTime`? I'm assuming it not possble to forward since the buffer didnt reach that point?

Comment: ya how do i edit the currenttime?

Comment: @CookieMonster im also having trouble with currenttime, mind if i bounty your question to ask about it?

Comment: Sure, go for it!